# Trigger in postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Good day,

I will appreciate any help that you may provide for the problem I am working on.

I have two tables below:

```
create table account (
account_number varchar(1000), 
branch_name varchar(1000), 
balance numeric(9,2)
);

insert into account (account_number, branch_name, balance) values ('acc1', 'Branch1', 100000);
insert into account (account_number, branch_name, balance) values ('acc2', 'Branch2', 150000);

create table depositor (cust_ID integer, account_number varchar(1000));
insert into depositor (cust_ID, account_number) values (1, 'acc1');
insert into depositor (cust_ID, account_number) values (2, 'acc2');
insert into depositor (cust_ID, account_number) values (3, 'acc3');
```

The task is **to create a SQL trigger to carry out the following action: If an account is deleted, then write a trigger to delete the dependent tuple(s) from the depositor table for every owner of the deleted account**.

Here is my progress - I assume there is a need to create function and appropriate trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $_$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM depositor WHERE depositor.account_number = OLD.account_number;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$_$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE DELETE ON account 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_function();
```

But I get the following error message:
"stack depth limit exceeded"

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship between `account` and `depositor`? Also add to your question the output(from `psql`) of  `\d+ account` and `\d+ depositor`.

Comment: Off-topic: return new doesn’t return anything after a delete: there is nothing new

Comment: @FrankHeikens what should I use instead? Are the other parts of trigger function correct?

Comment: Per here [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) you have to `RETURN` a non-null value. I didn't catch this earlier, but `RETURN NEW;` returns `NULL`. The suggested practice(from the linked doc) is to `RETURN OLD;`

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the fault of the trigger you are showing. There must be another trigger on `depositor` (or on `account`) that causes recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Laurenz. There are no any other triggers/constraints defined.

Comment: would you happen to know how to re-write scripts to achieve desired result?

Comment: I think in addition to this, if you're deleting thousands of records out of `account` in bulk, you can blow out the stack by spawning too many triggers at once. I think the depth may be configurable for Postgres.

Comment: @TarasKoval. Did you actually delete thousands of records? Even then it is doubtful it would trigger a stack depth error.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, up to 10 records were deleted.

Comment: @TarasKoval, then there is a recursion somewhere. Look at my comment to your question and provide the information requested as update to your question

Comment: I maintain that my answer is not far from the mark. Is there any `CONTEXT` with the error message?